# Is there a way for parsing the IAM users credentials inside a http body for the elasticsearch service?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, http, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm setting up some authentication methods in my elasticsearch endpoint in AWS. So, I'm trying to make HTTP requests to this endpoint parsing inside this body the IAM credentials but I have no idea how I can do it.

Maybe adding a field in the content body or header before the query or something like.

```
{
    "IAM-ARN":"SOMERANDOMID",
    "IAM-PASS":"SOMERANDOMPASS"
}
```

I would be so thankful for finding this solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can access using IAM credentials by signing the requests as if you were making a call to AWS api.

Here's an exapmple:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheAuthenticationHeader

Or you could just use an sdk. What language are you using?

Comment: Magus, I'm using Java. I've seen this documentation and now I understood how it works, but it's a bit hard to do. My main problem now is the signature calculation that always I receive a response with a message saying that my calculation is wrong.

Comment: You're probably forgetting to sort the parameters alphabetically! Since you're using java, have you considered using the sdk? https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2

Comment: Magus, no, I haven't. I have been trying to get the calculation result using 3rd part libs that I've found on github.

And I noticed that the aws sdk for elasticsearch has a built-in implementation (not a generic http one) in order to query over the elasticsearch. Question is, can I use only the 'signature libs/methods' and put the calculed result in the REST body?

Once again, thank you for helping me!

Comment: Yes you can. The AWS methods you'll see on the sdk concern que administration of ELK clusters, so all the ES stuff remains the same for you.